# Android studio debug 'app' not respect minifyEnabled

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, obfuscation

My gradle configuration is like below. I enabled minifyEnabled both for debug and release mode. But only in release mode, code is obfuscated. If I click the debug button on Android Studio, minifyEnabled seems not work, I still can debug with breakpoints, and proguard file does not take effect either. However, if I build a debug mode apk, the minifyEnabled flag and proguard file works which is verified by apk analytics.

Is it normal? What I know is that if you enabled minifyEnabled in debug mode, then the debugger would not work.

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.txt'
  }
  release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.txt'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`minifyEnabled` does not prevent to debug your code, it enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization as reported [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code).

You need to set `debuggable` flag to false to prevent debugging:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.txt'
  }
  release {
    debuggable false
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.txt'
  }
}
```

About the obfuscation only working in release buildType this may be due to your proguard rules specific for the debug build variant (`proguard-rules-debug.txt`). However, your code should be minified if you see it minified in the compiled apk, maybe you meant that it is debuggable even if minified.